# How to avoid copying all always in Visual C++ for Linux

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Using the Visual C++ for Linux (remote cross-platform) feature, each build goes through several steps:

1. Clean (if rebuild) the build folder
2. Copy all sources to the remote source folder
3. Build, Link.... etc.

The problem is when network is limited and several developers build many times a project of a several hundreds MB of sources.

Is it possible to synchronize sources without copying all always?

Comment: If you don't want to re-copy files, why are you doing a clean+rebuild?

Comment: I am not doing a clean+rebuild always, but it seem to copy all files always, even when using just "build" without clean.

Answer (score 0):

VCLinux supports incremental build but there is an issue which causes a rebuild when a  [header is changed](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/29). This is still there in VS 15.3 / VCLinux 1.0.7 and you'll see that it isn't scheduled for an early fix.

The two options to workaround the issue are: 1) convert to a `makefile` project or 2) split your project up into a number of smaller projects so the rebuild cost is lower.

Comment: If I understand your point, you refer to the build process, not to the copy/synchronize process?

Comment: Surely that's one and the same? Changed sources must be copied to the Linux target to synchronize for a meaningful build to take place. And, in VS, it's all lumped together in a single build operation. At least that's what I took your question to be about - building.

Comment: We are probably not speaking about the same: for remotely building, first files must be copied or synchronized to the remote location, and second, a build is required, including in my case cmake and make. The second part is not an issue. The first, could be copied all files always, or just incrementally; VS seem to copy all always, even what did not changed. Copying is long, so an incremental transfer is required to minimize costs.

Comment: I was refering to MSBuild projects. But the situation appears to be better in a makefile project in that untouched source files are not copied on build. Do you see the message "Skipping copying files as they are up to date." in your build output (verbosity-normal)? I'm using VS2017 15.3 / VCLinux 1.0.7.